# Is there a example in django 1.6 and python 3 to build a accounts app (include:register , login , and logout )

Tags: django

I do have read the offical document, but it describes every facility separately, after reading
'User authentication in Django' ,'First steps' , 'The model layer', 'The view layer' and 'The template layer' and 'Forms' , I still donot know how to create a account system.

there seems no django 1.6 and python 3 built account app source code or tutorial. where can I get them, thanks.

update:

All I what is a account app which I can plug it into any new project. Its urls will look like this:

accounts/register (the form class of this page is created from the class User in django.contrib.auth)

accounts/login

accounts/logout

accounts/profile (the form class of this page is created from the model which has a field `OneToOneField(User)`)

Comment: Django tutorial looks like a proper place to start https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: You have first to define what do you mean by "account system". What does it do except for allow user to log in, log out and sign up? Then you can think of implementation. I don't think there is specific "account system" tutorial just for you.

Comment: I do have read them from part 1 to part 6. but they have nothing to do with the register , login and logout system

Comment: In general, you have to create a model to contain user information, template to show sign up, log in and log out forms and view layer to allow user navigate between different templates. I'd suggest following whole tutorial implementing all suggested steps, not just reading it.

Comment: You can also use django.contrib.auth instead of implementing all this yourself https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

#Import a user registration form
from YourApp.forms import UserRegisterForm

# User Login View
def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            #This authenticates the user
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    #This logs him in
                    login(request, user)
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Not active")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Wrong username/password")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

# User Logout View
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

# User Register View
def user_register(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                return HttpResponse('User created succcessfully.')
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form'] = form
        #Pass the context to a template
        return render_to_response('register.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

In your forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')
```

In your urls.py:

```
# Accounts urls
url(r'accounts/login/$', 'YourApp.views.user_login'),
url(r'accounts/logout/$', 'YourApp.views.user_logout'),
url(r'accounts/register/$', 'YourApp.views.user_register'),
```

At last, in register.html:

```
<form action="/accounts/register/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
<h2>Please enter your details . . .</h2>
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, do you have the register view piece? Or where you get this code, the whole example will be the best. thanks

Comment: thanks. but when I tried http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/, an error comes up 'global name 'csrf' is not defined'. when tried 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/' or 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/', got Page not found (404)

Comment: Add: **from django.core.context_processors import csrf** on top of views.py.
Also if you need any help, please dump your code in your question, mainly your urls.py (multiple urls.py, if any)